# Generate tones of specific frequency on mac command line

Tags: macos, audio, terminal

I need to generate musical notes of a given frequency on the command line

Here is a list of the frequencies of notes http://www.phy.mtu.edu/~suits/notefreqs.html

For example:

```
$ some-app -frequency 523.25 -timeinseconds 3
```

It can be native mac, python or ruby tool. The fewer libraries I need to install then better. Maybe i can do something with mac: say or afplay?

This will be used for other project that will send music notes, and I want to hear it while working with it.

Comment: Are you comfortable with the command line? Are you able/willing to install and use http://mxcl.github.com/homebrew/ ?

Comment: @JohnMee: I want my terminal go beep beep..

Comment: [toot](http://github.com/vareille/toot) is a cross-platform C C++ file and command line tool that tries to call several sound generators to produce the beep

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's simple, old and unmaintained but take a look at https://github.com/psycotica0/tone-generator

```
$ brew install sdl
$ git clone https://github.com/psycotica0/tone-generator.git
$ cd tone-generator && make
$ ./generator 2600 2
```

Comment: Weird, it says: `Frequency '2600' is invalid`. I've OS X Mavericks 10.9.x

Comment: Works for me on yosemite.

Answer (score 16):

[SoX](http://sox.sourceforge.net/sox.html) works really good for this purpose and it's available in brew:

```
$ brew install sox
$ play -n synth 3 sin 523.25
```

You can also save the sound to a file:

```
$ play -n out.wav synth 3 sin 523.25
```

Comment: There's also a prebuilt mac binary.

Comment: You can also use musical notes instead of frequencies, e.g. `play -n synth 2 sine A4` (thanks @Bernhard Wagner)

Answer (score 5):

```
$ say "do ray me fa so la te do"
```

lols.

Comment: `$ say [[inpt PHON]] dOW rEY mIY fAA sOW lAA tIY dOW`