# Beep() function in Mac?

Tags: c++, macos

I was wondering whether or not there is anything basically identical to the Windows beep() function, which can be accessed with the windows.h header on Windows operating systems, on Macs (specifically with C++). I don't know if there anything else that will let me create simple sounds of specific lengths and frequencies.

Comment: Hope this might help... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13760504/generate-tones-of-specific-frequency-on-mac-command-line

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to play a system beep on Mac OS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7408785/is-there-a-way-to-play-a-system-beep-on-mac-os)

Comment: Maybe not an exact duplicate if you want a specific length and tone… @MarkSetchell's link sounds good.